# Id is not set in form object Thymeleaf Spring

Tags: html, spring, forms, jpa, thymeleaf

I am trying to edit a previous filled form using Thymeleaf and Spring Server.

This is the "previous form" which is POST in a Spring Server which saves correctly.

```
<form id="addingnovoatributo" action="#" th:action="@{'/addingoextraattributes/'}" th:object="${new_point_attributes}" method="post">
    <p>Id do Attribute: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly"/></p>
    <p>Id do Point: <input type="text" th:value="${point.id}" id="pointid" name="pointid" readonly="readonly"/></p>
    <p>Nome do atributo: <input type="text" th:field="*{attribute_name}" /></p>
    <p>Valor do atributo: <input type="text" th:field="*{attribute_value}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning"/></p>
</form>
```

The Spring Server saves it correctly (using JPA CrudRepository) and gives an unique ID for this object (which is a POJO class):

```
@Entity
public class Point_attributes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;
    public String attribute_name;
    public String attribute_value;
    public long pointid;

    public Point_attributes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public long getPointid() {
        return pointid;
    }
    public void setPointid(long pointid) {
        this.pointid = pointid;
    }
    public String getAttribute_name() {
        return attribute_name;
    }
    public void setAttribute_name(String attribute_name) {
        this.attribute_name = attribute_name;
    }
    public String getAttribute_value() {
        return attribute_value;
    }
    public void setAttribute_value(String attribute_value) {
        this.attribute_value = attribute_value;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I want to edit it using this form.
This is the Spring Controller method which sends the saved filled object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "EditOneAttri/{id_survey}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView EditOneAttr(@PathVariable("id_survey") long id_survey,@ModelAttribute Point_attributes mmPoint_attributes, Model model) 
{
    ModelAndView mModelAndView= new ModelAndView("editing_one_attri");
    mModelAndView.addObject("point_attributes",Points_attributesRepository.findById(id_survey));
    return mModelAndView;
}
```

We can see that the ID is not 0 (editing_one_attri.html):
[image]

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Editing one Attribute</title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
     <!-- Versión compilada y comprimida del CSS de Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Tema opcional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Versión compilada y comprimida del JavaScript de Bootstrap -->
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
</head>
<body th:inline="text">
  <div class="container theme-showcase"  role="main">
    <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2>Editing Attribute: [[${point_attributes.id}]]</h2>

                <form id="editing_question_survey" action="#" th:action="@{'/addingoextraattributes/'}" th:object="${point_attributes}" method="post">
                    <p>Id do Attribute: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" readonly="readonly"/></p>
                    <p>Id do Point: <input type="text" th:field="*{pointid}" readonly="readonly"/></p>
                    <p>Nome do atributo: <input type="text" th:field="*{attribute_name}" /></p>
                    <p>Valor do atributo: <input type="text" th:field="*{attribute_value}" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning"/></p>
            </form>
        </div>           
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring server receives the object but the id is always 0.
The rest of the values from the form are received correctly.
Anyone knows where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. The main mistake is that i didn't include an setter to the ID, so thymeleaf and/or html form was not able to set the ID in the object.

So, adding the `public void setId(){this.id=id;}` in the POJO class solved the problem.